# Binding warning when building Android project after upgrade to Xamarin 4.2.0.680

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

We began getting binding warnings during build of our Android specific project after upgrading Xamarin from 4.1.1.3 to 4.2.0.680 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Later update to Xamarin 4.2.0.703 did not fix this.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (2113): Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:


<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Concurrent" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XDocument" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Debug" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

It worked perfectly before upgrading Xamarin to 4.2.x. The same problem is seen on multiple developer machines and on our TFS Xaml build servers. Adding the binding redirections as suggested does not remove the warning, and neither does adding

```
<AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>True</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>
```

to the project in question as suggested by other similar questions.

Any suggestion on how to solve these warnings, other than just suppressing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this has been solved in Xamarin 4.2.1.64 (minor patch to [4.2.1.62](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#XVS_4.2.1.62)) or one of the versions that came after 4.2.0.680.

So basically the solution was to wait for an update to Xamarin that fixed it ;-).